# Why isn't my java file running (bash)

Tags: java, linux, bash

I am writing a bash script that will let me run a java file from a different directory but I am not sure why my already compiled java file wont run. Relevant code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "JavaAdd" -o "$1" == "JavaAddBad" ]
then
    echo "Testing $1"
    `java ../Source/Java/"$1"`

else  
    echo "Invalid File"
fi
```

this script is under a Script directory. So both subdirectories Script and Source are in the same directory. My compiled java file is under /Source/Java

Comment: You should `man java`.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter to `java` is not a path or file name.

It is a *class name*.

You can tell Java where to find it by specifiying a *classpath*.

```
java -cp ../somewhere/classes:../../somewhereElse/x.jar com.me.MyClass
```

The class will then be looked for in all the locations on the classpath. Each location can be either a directory or a jar file.

Also note that the directory you give to the classpath needs to put to the root of your class package hierarchy. So if your class is called `com.me.MyClass` and it is in a file at `../somewhere/classes/com/me/MyClass.class`, you need to include `../somewhere/classes` (not any of its subdirectories).

Also note that including a class path does not change the working directory for the program. It will still resolve relative paths when opening files based on the directory where you started it (completely unrelated to where the class files are).

Comment: I know that If I do 
java JavaAdd
the program will run, when I am in the same directory as the java file. So why can't I run it when im in a different directory?

Comment: How is it going to find your classes if you don't tell it where they are? By default, it only looks in the current directory.

Comment: How do I know where my class path is?

Comment: You have to set it (with -cp) to where your classes are.

Comment: So something like java -cp ../Source/Java/"$1" "$1"?

Comment: Make sure your classpath is set properly. Else use:  $ export CLASSPATH=.:<path1>:<path2>

Comment: I don't think the $1 needs to go to the class path. That is the class name, right? just `-cp ../Source/Java`.